# "not the room you are looking for?" text looks out of place

Tags: bug, chat, wording, information-display

I just noticed this text in the Tavern:

> [image]
>
> not the room you are looking for?

After a few minutes, I realized that this text seems to be pointing to the "there are other rooms, with..." text. But it made me think. Good design does not make me think. Therefore, this is not good design. Could we please do *something* to that orphaned text to make it easily comprehensible?

Comment: Chat bug. Will be ignored.

Answer (score 2):

So maybe the following result:

> Not the room you are looking for? [There are other rooms](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/), with 43 users currently talking in 11 rooms.